# Understanding every in .append

Tags: python

I am very new to coding and trying to bush up on some skills to help with investing.

The code's purpose is to scrape the wiki page for the tickers of all 500 S&P500 companies, to later pull historic data from.

```
import bs4 as bs
import pickle
import requests


def save_sp500_ticker():
    resp = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "lxml")
    table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'})
    tickers = []
    for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
        tickers = row.findAll('td')[0].text
        tickers.append(ticker)

    with open('sp500tickers.pickle', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(tickers, f)

    print(tickers)

    return tickers

save_sp500_ticker()
```

I am Then getting the error:

```
line 13, in save_sp500_ticker
    tickers.append(ticker)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I don't understand why, as the video teaching me has the exact same code without an error.

Comment: You typoed; you assigned the new item to `tickers`, replacing the `list`; you meant to assign to `ticker` (which you would then `append` to `tickers`). Change `tickers = row.findAll('td')[0].text` to `ticker = row.findAll('td')[0].text`.

Answer (score 1):

```py
tickers = []
for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    tickers = row.findAll('td')[0].text
    tickers.append(ticker)
```

You have set the `tickers` object to be an empty list and later on changed it to be a `str` (string) object by getting the `text` attribute. `str` objects do not have a `append` function, which is why your code is failing to run.

I believe you have mistakingly added a `s` to the end of `ticker`, which is reassigning the `tickers` object. You can easily correct it by removing the `s`.

```py
tickers = []
for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    ticker = row.findAll('td')[0].text
    tickers.append(ticker)
```